# Error Angular project : @angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm working on an Angular/NodeJs project, but since I added a Module, I keep getting errors.
I tried to update many packages following what I saw on the forum, but nothing works, I always end up with mismatching errors or missing stuff.
At the moment, here's the error blocking me:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\NodeJS\QualityHome\QualityHomeFront\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-1eOqnt\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "core-js": "2.6.12",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.5",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
```

What can I do?
(I cannot delete my node_modules folder because I'm not an admin.)

Thanks for your help!